# page control, ready event not working. Javascript windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, windows, html, visual-studio-2012

I just started to develop an app in Javascript, HTML5 and CSS3 for Windows 8.

My problem is that when calling the function `WinJS.Navigation.navigate (target-page.html)` the app actually loads the document HTML of the page, but the event `ready` of `target-page.js` is not executed by the application.

Answer (score 1):

The error was that in the "WinJS.Navigation.navigate ()" there wasn't the second arguments which is the state of the navigation, so the function became:"WinJS.Navigation.navigate (target-page.html, WinJS.Navigation.state)"

Thanks Bj

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a specific windows event. Without seeing your code, its hard to tell exactly what is going on. Try this:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", //Your event handler, false);
```